# When does a character return from being lost in vice?

Tags: blades-in-the-dark

In the section **Vice**, under **INDULGING YOUR VICE**, it says:

> Alternately, you may choose to release your character to be “lost in
> their vice” *during a game session*, allowing them to indulge off-camera
> while you play a different PC.

Further on specifying

> **Lost**. Your character vanishes for a few weeks. Play a different character until this one returns from their bender. When your
> character returns, they’ve also healed any harm they had.

If a player elects to release a character to their vice, is it that player's prerogative  to end the character's "bender"?

Answer (score 7):

### When you lose yourself to vice, you lose control.

> A vice is not a reliable, controllable habit. It's a risk -- and one that can drive your character to act against their own best interests.
>
> -- "Overindulgence", [from the SRD](https://bladesinthedark.com/vice)

You have no control over how long you're out when you overindulge. At least one whole score, almost always, unless you want to e.g. set up a dramatic flashback when everyone needs you most to reveal you were sleeping in the coffin strapped to your new Cutter lieutenant's back the entire time. But it's still the GM's call whether that goes through.

It's the GM's duty to **telegraph trouble before it strikes**, and **tell you the requirements or consequences and then ask**. They should be able to give you a rough idea of how long you'd be out if you lost yourself to vice, at least in relation to other important things the crew is planning.

But you should always think about it as missing at least one whole score.

#### Indulging your vice by getting lost in it works at the same tempo, but is slightly safer.

I see how the wording might be a bit confusing, but when you choose to be lost in vice to indulge, you're essentially skipping the session with your original character in order to avoid paying the cost in coin or rep to take the extra downtime action to indulge. Or, y'know, taking the chance to explore another playbook and character with a bit of a side benefit for who you're not playing. Not "you, the player, choose during a session that your character is lost in vice" but "you, the player, choose that your character is lost in vice for the length of a session".

What's a game session?

> A given game session is typically one score and the following downtime, plus exploration and discovery of a new opportunity.
>
> - "Playing a Session", *Blades in the Dark* p.3

Regardless of the actual time you have to sit down to play, whether one score takes place over a week's worth of lunch hours or you go through two scores on an all-day weekend retreat, the score cadence is probably a good bracket for how long "a game session" is intended to last.

You're still probably going to be out for at least one whole score, barring dramatic flashbacks to the contrary, but the GM doesn't have nearly as much narrative permission to get fuzzy around the edges of that if your crew has to operate up-tempo for whatever reason.

#### Yo dawg I heard you like getting lost in vice

Note that your quoted "alternately" doesn't say anything special about how much stress somebody recovers when they choose to get lost in vice for a session. Skipping a session is the alternate cost to taking an action during downtime; the character is still making the normal "indulge in vice" roll, which includes the possibility of overindulgence. If that happens, you can choose to get further lost, which is going to push your return to play even further and more unpredictably back.

Still probably at least one more score on top the one you're already giving up, though.

Comment: This seems accurate for overindulgence. But, you need not overindulge if you elect to lose yourself in vice.

Comment: @nonymous Ah, got you. This should help?

Comment: This seems about right to me. Except, can you cite the part about rolling to indulge when choosing to be lost? I might wait to see if there are alternatives, but this is really solid, I think.

Comment: @nonymous I would, except you already did. I've edited the last section.

Comment: Does it say that you should roll? I assumed that it cleared all stress.

Comment: @nonymous Both taking a downtime action to indulge and skipping a session in order to indulge are mentioned in the same paragraph before any rules on how to make the "indulge a vice" roll or how much stress it clears. I realize rules aren't perfect, and neither are online SRDs for all that they're easier to update, but "they were meant to work the same but the text isn't explicit about it" wins out over "they were meant to work differently but the text isn't explicit about it or about what the difference is, I'll just make it up" for me.

Comment: The text seems explicit to me. You give up a "session" in exchange for letting your character get lost in their vice. Presumably, though, the amount of stress cleared isn't mentioned because the *Lost* consequence assumes stress is cleared.